# Как добавить cryptopro в проекте flutter?

Tags: java, android, flutter, криптография

Собираю проект на Flutter, потребовалось подключение КриптоПро. Возник вопрос как это сделать.

Следую по [инструкция](https://docs.cryptopro.ru/android/samples/ACSPInClientApp/preparing_to_run?id=%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%84%d0%b8%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%bd%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b0) я сделал следующие:

1. Скачал КриптоПро CSP для андроид
2. В папку android -> app я положил папку libs
3. Далее в папке android -> app в файле build.gradle добавил
   следующие

android {

```
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/Sign.CP'
        exclude 'META-INF/Digest.CP' }
```

}

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
}
```

Запускаю flutter, ошибок нет. Пытаюсь сделать import libs для проверки например Получение закрытого ключа и сертификата из ключевого контейнера.

Однако ничего не импортится.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/lib/JInitCSP.aar';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Welcome to Flutter',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Welcome'),
        ),
        body: const Center(
          child:,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, какую и как мне двигаться дальше.

Answer (score 0):

> Пытаюсь сделать import libs

Где вы это делаете?

> Однако ничего не импортится и подозреваю.

Что подозреваете?

> Подскажите пожалуйста, какую и как мне двигаться дальше.

Двигайтесь в сторону [каналов платформы](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: Мои "подозрения" это опечатка. Я делаю импорт в главный файл (Mian.dart) для инициализации провайдера. За ссылку спасибо.

https://docs.cryptopro.ru/android/samples/ACSPClientApp/preparing_to_run